# Make circular Graph instead of the line Graph in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Lets say I have the following case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd 

d = {'label': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'size': [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], 'dist': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df 
G = nx.Graph()
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_node(row['label'], pos=(row['dist'], 0), size=row['size'])
biggest_node = 1
for node in G.nodes:
    if node != biggest_node:
        G.add_edge(biggest_node, node)

nx.draw(G,
        pos={node: attrs['pos'] for node, attrs in G.nodes.items()},
        node_size=[node['size'] * 100 for node in G.nodes.values()],
        with_labels=True
        )
plt.show()
```

This example comes from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69837985/create-undirected-graph-in-networkx-in-python-from-pandas-dataframe) to my previous question about the same issue.

what I want to do now is to obtain a similar Graph, but instead of the line, I would like to have nodes aligned on the circumference. The rest stays the same! Is there any way, one can obtain that? Obviously, the furthest point from the origin will be on the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

As, I understand you have only one "origin"(node for which dist is 0), so you can use `pos=spring_layout(G)` as it uses fruchterman-Reingold algorithm to draw the graph, which draws a circular graph when there is only one parent node.

```
nx.draw(G,
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G),
    node_size=[node['size'] * 100 for node in G.nodes.values()],
    with_labels=True
    )
```

[image]